# Common elements in data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics, intersection

I have three data frames, with a lot of information and the following row names:

```
ENSG00000000971 ENSG00000000971 ENSG00000000971
ENSG00000004139 ENSG00000004139 ENSG00000003987
ENSG00000005001 ENSG00000004848 ENSG00000004848
ENSG00000005102 ENSG00000002330 ENSG00000002330
ENSG00000005486 ENSG00000005102 ENSG00000006047
...             ...             ...
```

What I want to do, is to find all the entries (row names) that are common in *at least* 2 of the data frames. I.e., the end result should be a single list, like this:

```
ENSG00000000971
ENSG00000004139
ENSG00000004848
ENSG00000005102
ENSG00000002330
```

How do I go about doing this? I tried doing this:

```
shared.DESeq2.edgeR = data.frame(row.names(res.DESeq2) %in% row.names(res.edgeR))
shared.DESeq2.limma = data.frame(row.names(res.DESeq2) %in% row.names(res.limma))
shared.edgeR.limma = data.frame(row.names(res.edgeR) %in% row.names(res.limma))
shared = merge(merge(shared.DESeq2.edgeR, shared.DESeq2.limma), shared.edgeR.limma)
```

... where the three `res.[DESeq2/edgeR/limma]` are the three data frames, but this takes ages to run (I didn't even let it finish, so I don't know if it actually works). I have some code that does this for the elements that are common to *all three* data frames, but I'm also interested in the ones that are common to two or more data frames, but I can't really find a good way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Can any of the dataframes contain duplicates?

Comment: No, there are no duplicates of the row names in any of the data frames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this example:

```
#dummy data, with real data we would do: res.DESeq2_rn <-row.names(res.DESeq2)
res.DESeq2_rn <- letters[1:4]
res.edgeR_rn <- letters[3:8]
res.limma_rn <- letters[c(1,3,8,10)]

#get counts
res <- table(c(res.DESeq2_rn, res.edgeR_rn, res.limma_rn))
res
# a b c d e f g h j 
# 2 1 3 2 1 1 1 2 1 

#result
names(res)[ res>=2 ]
#[1] "a" "c" "d" "h"
```

**EDIT:** benchmarking suggests solution by @vaettchen is the winner!

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)
# create a large random character vector (this takes a lot of time!)
set.seed(123)
myNames <- sapply(1:1000000,
                  function(i)paste( sample( letters, 8, replace = TRUE ), collapse = "" ))
A <- sample(myNames,1000)
B <- sample(myNames,2000)
C <- sample(myNames,3000)

#benchmarking 3 options
myBench <- microbenchmark(
  Which={
    res <- c(A,B,C)
    out1 <- unique( res[ which( duplicated( res ) ) ] ) },
  Table={ 
    res <- c(A,B,C)
    y <- table( res )
    out2 <- names( y )[ y >= 2 ] },
  Intersect={ 
    out3 <- 
      unique(
        c(intersect(A,B),
          intersect(A,C),
          intersect(B,C)))},
  times=1000)

print(myBench)
qplot(y=time, data=myBench, colour=expr) + scale_y_log10()

Unit: microseconds
      expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval cld
     Which   266.837   280.4190   527.8266   288.2680   301.2475  59255.34  1000  a 
     Table 32167.286 32739.5945 34851.2260 33072.0825 33524.2550 108176.22  1000   b
 Intersect   450.965   472.3965   667.3316   484.7725   499.8650  60266.54  1000  a
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, taking @zx8754's sample data:

```
# dummy data
res.DESeq2 <- letters[ 1:4 ]
res.edgeR <- letters[ 3:8 ]
res.limma <- letters[ c( 1, 3, 8, 10 ) ]

# combine into one vector                  
res <- c( res.DESeq2, res.edgeR, res.limma )
res
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "a" "c" "h" "j"

# result
unique( res[ which( duplicated( res ) ) ] )
[1] "c" "d" "a" "h"
```

## EDIT

@zx8754's answer is accepted, for all good reasons, it is clean and elegant. Purely as a matter of my intellectual curiosity, I looked into performance differences between his and my approach for large samples, and found it interesting enough to post it:

```
# create a large random character vector (this takes a lot of time!)
res <- rep( "x", 1000000 )
for( i in 1:1000000) 
    res[ i ] <- paste( sample( letters, 8, replace = TRUE ), collapse = "" )
head( res )
[1] "vsvkljgr" "ulxhqnas" "upqqtrdk" "pynuaihp" "srjtnvqm" "mxnlytvd"

# vaettchen:
system.time( x <- unique( res[ which( duplicated( res ) ) ] ) )
 user  system elapsed 
0.173   0.000   0.171 
x
[1] "zlzlwinb" "wielycpx"

# zx8754
system.time( { y <- table( res ); z <- names( y )[ y >= 2 ] } )
  user  system elapsed
18.945   0.020  19.058 
z
[1] "wielycpx" "zlzlwinb"
```

For big enough data or repeated calls, the difference may matter a lot. A brief explanation of what my code does:

- `duplicated( res )` creates a vector of length res that contains logical TRUE or FALSE, depending upon whether or not a character string appears repeatedly
- `which( ... )` turns that into a vector of indices where that value is TRUE
- `res[ ... ]` extracts the actual character value of res at the indexed position, and
- `unique( ... )` reduces each character value to only one appearance, which is the answer @Sajber was looking for (as I understand it)

Comment: Yes, benchmarking suggests your approach is fastest. See my edited post.